# AngularJS update value from multiple textbox values

Tags: html, angularjs

I have three product details and I have the total price at the bottom.
If user changes the quantity of one item, then the total price should be updated.

I have

```
<div>
<p class="desc">{{item.desc}}</p>
<p class="price">{{item.price}}</p>
<p class="qty"><input type="text" maxlength="2" ng-model="item.qty"></p>
</div>

<div>
<p class="desc">{{item.desc}}</p>
<p class="price">{{item.price}}</p>
<p class="qty"><input type="text" maxlength="2" ng-model="item.qty"></p>
</div>

<div>
<p class="desc">{{item.desc}}</p>
<p class="price">{{item.price}}</p>
<p class="qty"><input type="text" maxlength="2" ng-model="item.qty"></p>
</div>

Total Price: $XXXX.XX
```

I get the above divs using loop.

When user changes the quantity in any of the three, then I need to update the total price and display below.

Suppose:

```
DIV1 has price $10 qty 1
DIV2 has price $20 qty 1
DIV3 has price $30 qty 1
```

The total is $60

If user changes the quantity of DIV2 to 3, then I need to get the total as $100

How do I do this in AngularJS?

Comment: The example code has all three divs in the same scope, so they'll both display and affect the same `item`. Try showing your scopes in more realistic example, this will help us answer.

Comment: Have you had a look at my answer? Let me know if you have any trouble with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is working [DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/gyS53O3ZeLfQIOX76vfk?p=preview) for your problem.I refactored your multiple div's to single one using `ng-repeat` and to keep track of quantity change I've used `ng-change` to re calculate the price every time the quantity changes.

In HTML

```
<body ng-controller="dobController">
     <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
<p class="desc">{{item.desc}}</p>
<p class="price">{{item.price}}</p>
<p class="qty"><input type="text" maxlength="2" ng-change="updatePrice()" 
 ng-model="item.qty"></p>
</div>
Total Price is {{totalPrice}}
  </body>
```

In JS

```
$scope.totalPrice = 0;

        $scope.items = [{
            "item": "phone",
            "desc": "Iphone 4",
            "price": 100,
            "qty": 1
        }, {
            "item": "phone",
            "desc": "Iphone 5",
            "price": 200,
            "qty": 2
        }, {
            "item": "phone",
            "desc": "Iphone 6",
            "price": 300,
            "qty": 3
        }, {
            "item": "phone",
            "desc": "Iphone 7",
            "price": 400,
            "qty": 1
        }];
        $scope.updatePrice = function() {
            var total = 0;
            angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
                total += item.qty * item.price;
            });
            $scope.totalPrice = total;
        };

        $scope.updatePrice();
```

Hope this helps in resolving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be inefficient to iterate through all of your items again, you can consider the following method if it's not a concern for you.

Try making a custom filter for the items:

E.g. put this in your JavaScript:

```
yourApp.filter('totalPrice', function() {
    return function(items) {
        var total = 0;

        // iterate through all the items to sum the price
        angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
            total += item.qty * item.price;
        }.bind(this));

        return total;
    };
});
```

And then use that filter in the total price div inside the template:

```
<div>
    Total Price: {{ items | totalPrice }}
</div>
```

And you can do any formatting you want (e.g. adding dollar sign, commas, etc.) inside that filter definition.